# Shoot bullet based on mouse y position?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Any help is much appreciated!

I have a character that shoots right now.  I instantiate a bullet at runtime, and set its position / rotation to be the same as a "spawn point" in the world.  How would I go about having the bullet "hit" where the mouse is pointing, rather than just moving straight forward when shot?

```
//Bullet instaniate code
bulletSpawned = Instantiate(bullet.transform, 
bulletSpawnPoint.transform.position,  
bulletSpawnPoint.transform.rotation);
bulletSpawned.rotation = bulletSpawnPoint.transform.rotation;
//Bullet move code
transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * bulletSpeed); maxDistance += 1 * Time.deltaTime;
    if (maxDistance >= bulletFlyTime)
    {
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }
```

Comment: I can't fully answer this question but I can provide some hints. There are multiple tasks involved. 1) Detect a mouse click. 2) Determine the location of the click within your game screen space. 3) Calculate the Vector from the bullet position to the mouse click 4) Update the vector of the bullet. Unity3d provides ways to do these things. But I don't know them. However, I know there are Tutorials for Unity3d for doing this sort of thing. Viewing one would certainly be helpful.

Comment: Also, if this is a game, there is a whole [stack exchange site for game development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/).  You could try asking your question there.  `Unity` is the top tag over there.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks - your comments led me down a rabbit hole and found a solution that worked for me.  Below is the code I used.

```
RaycastHit hit;
    Ray ray2 = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    if (Physics.Raycast(ray2, out hit))
    {
        Debug.Log("The ray hit at: " + hit.point);
        bulletSpawnPoint.transform.LookAt(hit.point);
    }
```